# Stuck on using java runtime backup and restore mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using java RunTime to execute mysql command to backup and restore database, but it just cannot work.

My Environment: Mac OS Big Sur, arm64,Java 8

At first, I use

```
String command = "mysqldump -uxxx -pxxx myDataBase > /myFolder/backup.sql"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command);
```

try to backup the database, but it seems there is an issue with the ">" in the command

so I change to

```
String command = "mysqldump -uxxx -pxxx myDataBase -r /myFolder/backup.sql"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command);
```

and It is working

Then I try to resotre from this .sql file

```
String command = "mysql -uxxx -pxxx -r myDataBase < /myFolder/backup.sql"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command);
```

There is no error report ,but the database it not restore. I run this command in terminal, it just work.

I thought it might be the "<" issue, so I change code to

```
String[] command = {"/bin/bash", "-c" , "mysql -uxxx -pxxx -r myDataBase < /myFolder/backup.sql"}
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command);
```

Still, no error but not working , I try to run this command in terminal, but I got error:

```
/bin/bash -c /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql -uxxx -pxxx
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Now I am totally confused, why I got "(using password: NO)" when the "-pxxx" is using?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: wouldnt you have to drop the existing db and recreate it before restoring?

Comment: No you don't need to delete the old database. At least you should not. the sql script will drop all tables and create them new which are in the dump file. So if you already added new tables they won't be affected for example

Comment: What happens if you CD into the mysl/bin directory and then start with sh mysql -uxxx -pxxx

Comment: Hi  Claus Bönnhoff ,  the .sql file which is dump from mysqldump will drop the table first then recreate it. As I mention above, same command will restore successfully while not working in Java RunTime.

Comment: According to the `mysql` manual page, `-uxxx` should be `-u xxx` or `--user=xxx`.  (So `-uxxx -pxxx` *could* be being interpreted as meaning `--user=-pxxx` ... "consuming" the password.)

Comment: Hi Stephen C, that's not the problem,using --user=xxx won't help

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, just use the

```
ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("/bin/zsh","-c","mysql -uxxx -pxxx -r -vvv myDataBase < xxxx/backup.sql");
pb.redirectOutput(new File("xxxx/log.txt"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

I still don't know the exact reason to cause this, but it just work and I have to do the further job.